# pyhs2 cant finish downloading

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, pip

last lines in downloading python2 
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhs2': Permission denied

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_hduser/pyhs2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cKJDI5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_hduser/pyhs2
Storing debug log for failure in /home/hduser/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Are you running as a user with write permissions on `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`?  Apparently not -- so, `chmod` that directory, or, run with `sudo`.

Comment: And what do you get from `ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`?  If e.g that was mounted from an NFS file system, it's quite possible that `root` might lack permission to write there.

Comment: drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff 4096 Dec 24 17:36 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: and i got this error error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1